# How to solve Connection Timed Out Error for Postgres connection using Airflow

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, airflow, psycopg2

I have a connection timeout when I am running airflow DAGs. It occurs daily when I am running it in the morning. It happens on the same task step everytime when it's on its first attempt.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host “hostname.domain.com” (99.999.999.99) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 77777?
```

I checked the database connection and it is connecting fine. My database is not having any downtime.

I copied this error from the logs you can get from the airflow UI. Does anybody know what the cause could be for this error?